# Do I have to activate "denoising" when using the denoise node in the compositor?

Tags: denoise

[image]
So here's a regular denoise node setup. I just learned this recently.

[image]

But normally, I wouldn't denoise in the compositor. I would just denoise using Optix by ticking this.

Based on my understanding, the compositor method is better (Please correct me if I'm wrong)

My question is : If I were to denoise in the compositor, would I still have to tick the denoising box?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you don't, as you said yourself, you have 2 options by default:
Denoise in render settings or
Denoise in composition...

Composition denoise will work if you don't enable denoising in render settings, but it will still work even if you enable it in render settings, you just have to use **Noisy Image** instead of **Image**

just to clarify:

If you don't enable denoising in render settings - use **Image** value for composition
If you enable denoising in render settings - use **Noisy Image** value for composition (this value is only available if you activated denosing)

Comment: The _Noisy Image_ output is not only available if you enabled denoising (you're talking about "denoising in render settings" here), it is also available along with some more data outputs if you enable _Denoising Data_ under _View Layer Properties_ > _Passes_ > _Data_. The difference is, if _Denoising_ is enabled in the _Render Properties_, the _Image_ output will give you an already denoised image as render result, whereas just enabling _Denoising Data_ will have the same output for _Image_ and _Noisy Image_ which makes it necessary to denoise in the _Compositor_.

Comment: @SohailNordin Additionally to the answer and my comment: I put up a simple scene which rendered without any denoising enabled in **4.87** seconds.
If I enable _Denoising_, it rendered in **12.28 s**. Instead of using the already denoised image but plugging _Noisy Image_ into a _Denoise_ node in compositing, it rendered in **13.83 s**, but the result looked much better.

Comment: @SohailNordin If I disable _Denoising_ and enable _Denoising Data_ so I have to denoise in compositing and use _Denoising Normal_ and _Denoising Albedo_, the render took only **9.61 s**.
Just denoising in _Compositor_ without enabling anything the render time was **6.85 s** and the result was just as good as the other denoised images (and better as the "directly" denoised image).
All in all, the _Denoise_ node in the _Compositor_ works quite good, I always prefer it over the _Denoising_ option in the _Render Properties. _Denoising Data_ I only use sometimes, when the denoise is a bit blurry.